# Why might Ordnance Survey codes all be out by 500m?

Tags: geocoding, ordnance-survey

I've been given a set of UK Ordnance Survey geocodes, but I think they're all off by about 500 metres.

Below is an example.

Could someone confirm to me that the codes are wrong, not my calculations?

The OS geocode that I've been given is `SO7567`, for a place called Abberley, in Worcestershire.

My script converts this to `52.30136731, -2.36798287` here: http://goo.gl/maps/9a3Yu However, Abberley is here, about 500 metres north: http://goo.gl/maps/OAD9L

[This conversion site](http://www.onlineconversion.com/map_osg-latlon.htm) suggests my calculations are correct, and it is indeed the original coders (who looked at Abberley, and decided that its Ordnance Survey code was `SO7567`) who were out of whack.

Could anyone suggest why they might all be out by exactly this amount?

Could it be a projection issue?

I'm not an geographer, and the person who gave them to me swears they should be right!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example grid reference only has 4 digits and thus specifies a location which is 1km square, so plenty of room for a 500m error there.

See [Ordnance Survey grid digits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordnance_Survey_National_Grid#Grid_digits) for examples of numerical resolution. More digits will give you more accuracy.